# Unobtrusive jQuery and Rails with AJAX and form validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, forms

I am looking for a way to call successfully custom function from
submitHandler to do proper ajax post.

Here is my custom function:

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
this.submit(function() {
$.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
return false;
})
return this;
};
```

Before using validate plugin I had following which worked fine:

$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my_form").submitWithAjax();
   }

Now I have added the validation part and have no idea how to call my
custom submitWithAjax function??

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#my_form").validate({

/*Validations - works perfectly!! */

},

submitHandler: function(form) {

/* $("#my_form").submitWithAjax(); - this works but
introduces recursion */

/* how to call custom subitWithAjax() ????? */

}

});
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your custom plugin only adds a submit event handler which won't work with the validator plugin 
try this

```
$("#my_form").validate({
    /*Validations - works perfectly!! */
},
submitHandler: function(form){
    $.post(this.action, $(form).serialize(), null, "script");
});
```

Comment: That is true but I am also doing jQuery and ajax setup before each ajax request:
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
      'beforeSend': function(xhr{xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept",     "text/javascript")}
      });

with your suggestion the 'before send' will not be called.

Comment: @bogumbiker The beforeSend event gets triggered by the $.post method your are calling not by the submit event. Your beforeSend function will still work.

Comment: I think you are correct, however the server side code (ror) does not handle the request properly anymore. The authenticity_token is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found your answer, bogumbiker. I ended up including rails.js from the jquery-ujs library:

http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

and calling the callRemote() function instead of submitWithAjax() after validation.  Worked for me in Rails 3.

Comment: @jonphillips - thanks a lot for this. I just started new project in rails 3 and will give it a try. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using [rails.js](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js), so I decided to call the validation within the `ajax:beforeSend` callback (described [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)).  Here is the workaround:

```
$('form').live('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, status){
  var form = $(this);
  form.validate({
    /* validation options go here */
  });
  if (!form.valid()) {
    return false;
  }
});
```